# How to access WordPress Plugin Variable/MySQL Data?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin that is an extension to woocommerce. This plugin stores information under the MySQL Table "wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta". Under the column "meta_key", there is "_wc_deposit_meta". Next to the column "meta_key" I have "meta_value". Under the "meta_value" you find `a:5:{s:6:"enable";s:3:"yes";s:7:"deposit";d:197.67000000000001591615728102624416351318359375;s:9:"remaining";d:401.32999999999998408384271897375583648681640625;s:5:"total";d:599;s:5:"ratio";d:1;}`. While learning PHP I have never came across a value like this. Could someone explain what this value is and how do I access the value for "deposit". Is this just another example of a multidimensional array?

I have been trying to access this value by `$my_order = $order->get_items();` in my functions.php, which is returning an array. I see the correct array called "_wc_deposit_meta" with this weird value that I do not know how to access because of the commas and colons.

Sorry for the noob question but I have been trying to research this buy could not find a simple black and white answer. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WordPress needs to store multi-dimensional data into a field it applies PHP's [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function to convert the data into a storable string, then [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) when reading the value to return it to it's proper data structure.

The anatomy of serialized data definitions are described in the first comment on PHP's `serialize()` documentation:

> - String: `s:[size]:[value];`
> - Integer: `i:[value];`
> - Double: `d:[value];`
> - Boolean: `b:[value];` (does not store "true" or "false", does store '1' or '0')
> - Null: `N;`
> - Array: `a:[size]:{[key definition];[value definition];(repeated per element)}`
> - Object: `O:[strlen(object name)]:[object name]:[object size]:{s:[strlen(property name)]:[property name]:[property definition];(repeated per property)}`

More specifically, WordPress uses it's own [`maybe_serialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) and [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) wrappers to mitigate the chance of (un)serializing when not necessary.

In the particular serialized data you are working with, your deposit is represented by the key/value definitions `s:7:"deposit";d:197.67000000000001591615728102624416351318359375;`. To alter your deposit value by hand, you would modify the double after `d:`. To modify the value programmatically in WordPress, use the [Metadata API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) to query the field using a "get" function (which will implicitly unserialize it), modify the value of the `'deposit'` field in the returned associative array, then save the new value using an "update" function from the Metadata API.

Answer (score 1):

The value that you're looking at has been `serialized()` and stored in the database. Simply take that variable and use `unserialize()` on it, like so:

```
$myVal = unserialize($databaseColumn);
```

1. [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
2. [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)